# Python: Simpson's rule, negative answer for positive area under the curve?

Tags: python, scipy, numerical-integration, simpsons-rule

I have

```
y1=[  9.49110000e-004   4.74145420e-004   1.41847155e-008   3.33228420e-028
       3.76352289e-081   4.48206815e-193   0.00000000e+000   0.00000000e+000
       0.00000000e+000   0.00000000e+000   0.00000000e+000] 

x=[ 112.  111.97667396  111.90666665  111.78989038  111.62619837  
     111.41538384  111.15717866  110.85125168  110.49720654  110.09457901
    109.64283388]
```

All the `y` values are positive, so the area under the curve should be positive. But when I try to use Simpson's rule to integrate

```
  from scipy.integrate import simps
  b= simps(y1, x)

  print b
```

I am getting `-2.45630795891e-05` as the answer. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`x` is decreasing, so you're integrating from right to left. This flips the sign of the result.

Comment: I reversed both `y1` and `x`, I still got the same answer.

Comment: @HuShu: Well, [when I reverse them](http://ideone.com/o3tepD), the answer comes out positive.

Comment: Wow! Thanks. I don't know how/why this happened, but after I restarted my kernel and reversed the order, it gave me a positive number.